# error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available

Tags: r, installation

I am installing R. I am getting this error when runing ./configure :

```
checking for history_truncate_file... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

Any hint,
Thanks

Answer (score 67):

Use the following command will solve this problem

```
./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no
```

**--with-x=no** turns off the [X Windows System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) . It is the GUI for the Linux and Unix-like OS. My computer has no X Windows installed, so I turn off.
But I highly recommand to install readline library before R installtion with '--with-readline=yes', as the command operation style is quitely unfriendly with '--with-readline=no' . See more [libreadline](http://www.bioinf.org.uk/software/profit/doc/node17.html) installation in linux for more details

you can use the following command for more install configuration details

```
./configure --help
```

Comment: Can you share your solution please? I am experiencing the same issue, even though I have installed readline and added the lib directory to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH I still get the same error

Comment: I have the same issue, and can't decide whether to turn it off after reading you suggestion. I'm installing in a system that does not have any kind of GUI, and can only be accessed via terminal (e.g. ssh). Would turning it off change the appearance of the interactive console? I'm considering also install R studio Server.

Answer (score 40):

on I found problem on compiling R 3.1.1 so as a part of solution , i recommend to install the below libraries first before you compile this R and use

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install fort77
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev  libblas-dev gfortran
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
sudo apt-get install gobjc++
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libreadline-dev
```

Thank you other people who posted and kept the knowledge going..

Comment: Great, this answer solved my problem when installing R 3.2.4-revised

Comment: For a similar problem with R 4.1.2, I needed `libbz2-dev`,  `libpcre2-posix2`,  `libpcre2-dev` too.

Answer (score 16):

I think you need the GNU readline package. You can install it with apt-get, aptitude, or the appropiate tool for your distribution. In Ubuntu:

```
aptitude install libreadline-dev
```

Answer (score 13):

On Linux version 2.6.18-371.3.1.el5 (centos) the following worked for me

```
yum install readline-devel
```

and use `--with-x=no` in configure option as mentioned by others

Answer (score 5):

I added this in the file taken here:
http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2012/08/installing-the-development-version-of-r-on-ubuntu-alongside-the-current-version-of-r.html

```
CXXFLAGS="-ggdb -pipe -Wall -pedantic -I/usr/include/readline5" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/readline5" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64/readline5" \
```

Comment: In my case, the header is in /usr/local/include/readline/ and this is added to CPPFLAGS. The library so file is in /usr/local/lib/, but the R configure still could not see it.  Not sure what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Centos 7, building R-3.5.0, If you want to install in /data/R-3.0.5.

```
wget https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf R-3.5.0.tar.gz
cd R-3.5.0.tar.gz
mkdir -p /data/R-3.0.5   
yum group install "Development tools" -y
yum install readline-devel -y
yum install xorg-x11-server-devel libX11-devel libXt-devel -y
yum yum install libbz2-devel -y
yum install lzma -y
yum install xz xz-devel -y
yum install pcre pcre-devel -y
yum install libcurl-devel -y
yum install texinfo -y
yum install texinfo-tex -y
yum install texlive -y
yum install texlive-fonts-extra -y
yum install levien-inconsolata-fonts -y
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y

./configure --prefix=/data/R-3.0.5 '--with-cairo' \
'--with-jpeglib' '--with-readline' '--with-tcltk' \
'--with-blas' '--with-lapack' '--enable-R-profiling' \
'--enable-R-shlib' \
'--enable-memory-profiling'

make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means your system cannot find the required package. On Ubuntu, you can refer to this document to install all missing dependencies. It works for R 4.0

https://github.com/Jiefei-Wang/Painless-R-compilation-and-installation-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by installing the ncurses 6.2 package available here : https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/

When you run the configure script, the step here fails :

```
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
```

With ncurses installed, configure can proceed a few steps later

```
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... yes
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... yes
```