# How to get geoR and sp R packages working in AWS Linux EC2 AMI

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, tcl, tk-toolkit, geor

My end goal is to be able to use the geoR and sp packages in R on an AWS EC2 Linux instance. The first hurdle is getting an older version of R since 3.3 doesn't support TCL/TK (at least that I've found).

After unpacking R-3.2.5.tar.gz and following the instructions in the INSTALL file (along with [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18590261/3865662) configure options), a search in the config.log shows the following for TCL and TK:

```
configure:32908: checking for tclConfig.sh  
configure:32950: checking for tclConfig.sh in library (sub)directories  
configure:33143: checking for tcl.h  
conftest.c:228:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory  
 #include <tcl.h>  
config.status:1893: creating src/library/tcltk/DESCRIPTION  
config.status:1893: creating src/library/tcltk/Makefile  
config.status:1893: creating src/library/tcltk/src/Makefile  
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_CPPFLAGS_set=  
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_CPPFLAGS_value=  
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_LIBS_set=  
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_LIBS_value=  
r_cv_header_tcl_h=no  
TCLTK_CPPFLAGS=''  
TCLTK_LIBS=''  
TCL_CONFIG=''  
use_tcltk='no'
```

R installs successfully, but running `capabilities("tcltk")` confirms that something went wrong, as it returns `FALSE`.

Following the hints [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222696), I searched for tclConfig.sh and tkConfig.sh, and realized I hadn't installed the appropriate dependencies, namely tcl-devel, and tk-devel.

Running `yum list available` shows a package for `tcl-devel.x86_64` but nothing for `tk`. I downloaded source files for TCL and TK from [here](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html), but couldn't find source files for any `devel` packages.

So now I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Has anyone been through this process that can shed some light on it?

---

**UPDATE**

After reading the comment below, I'm afraid I didn't do my due diligence in researching TCL/TK and R 3.3.

My very early efforts to troubleshoot the whole problem consisted of the following workflow- First, without even considering an older version of R, I ran `install.packages("geoR")` in 3.3.2. This resulted in `installation of package 'geoR' had non-zero exit status`, along with:

`Error: package 'tcltk' does not have a namespace`
`ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'geoR'`

So, naturally, I ran `install.packages("tcltk")` which resulted in `package 'tcltk' is not available (for R version 3.3.2)`

As I mentioned before, this was very early on. I took the message literally and didn't think to look further into TCL/TK for 3.3, but instead started looking to get an earlier version of R, since I had been successfully running geoR and sp on another system that had R 3.2.5.

Comment: What do you mean 3.3 doesn't support tcl/tk?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your comment. In retrospect, I didn't look into TCL/TK and R 3.3. See update above--

Comment: Looks like your version of R isn't but with tcltk support. It's not a package, but rather something configured during the R build process.