# How can I install R in Linux server? When I run the ./configure command I am getting

Tags: r

I want to install R in Linux Server. I was going through the site: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html.

When I run the `./configure` command I am getting the following:

```
[root@sd-cd1a-b9e0 R-devel]# ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build-specific script './config.site'
checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for which... /usr/bin/which
checking for less... /usr/bin/less
checking for gtar... /bin/gtar
checking for tex... no
checking for pdftex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
checking for pdflatex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
checking for makeindex... no
checking for texi2any... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
checking for texi2dvi... no
checking for kpsewhich... no
checking for latex inconsolata package... checking for unzip... 
/usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for gzip... /bin/gzip
checking for bzip2... /usr/bin/bzip2
checking for firefox... no
checking for mozilla... no
checking for galeon... no
checking for opera... no
checking for xdg-open... no
checking for kfmclient... no
checking for gnome-moz-remote... no
checking for open... /usr/bin/open
using default browser ... /usr/bin/open
checking for acroread... no
checking for acroread4... no
checking for xdg-open... no
checking for evince... no
checking for xpdf... no
checking for gv... no
checking for gnome-gv... no
checking for ggv... no
checking for okular... no
checking for kpdf... no
checking for open... /usr/bin/open
checking for working aclocal... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for yacc... no
checking for notangle... false
checking for realpath... false
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ -g -O2 can compile C++ code... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
checking whether g++ can compile ObjC++... no
checking whether  can compile ObjC++... no
checking for Objective C++ compiler... no working ObjC++ compiler found
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... 
func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... gawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared 
libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared 
libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared 
libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gfortran PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gfortran static flag -static works... no
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports 
shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking readline/history.h usability... no
checking readline/history.h presence... no
checking for readline/history.h... no
checking readline/readline.h usability... no
checking readline/readline.h presence... no
checking for readline/readline.h... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... no
checking for main in -ltermcap... no
checking for main in -ltermlib... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not 
available
```

When I run the make command I am getting the following issue:

> [root@sd-cd1a-b9e0 R-devel]# make
>         make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Can anyone please help how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? Your system is missing the `readline` library. Under Ubuntu, you should install it through `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev`. I suggest also to configure with `./configure --enable-R-shlib --enable-memory-profiling`. You likely have to install a bunch of other system libraries (for instance `libX11-dev`, `libpng12-dev`, `libjpeg-dev`, `libxt-dev` and others).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473547/error-with-readline-yes-default-and-headers-libs-are-not-available)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Right now I am getting the following error once I run 
     ./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no

Error:
     checking for inflateInit2_ in -lz... no
     checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and 
     headers are required

Answer (score 1):

Your `./configure` command failed as you can see at the bottom of the log:

```
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not 
available
```

Here's SO answer to the error above:
  [error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473547/error-with-readline-yes-default-and-headers-libs-are-not-available)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I am getting the following error once I run ./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no Error: checking for inflateInit2_ in -lz... no checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required

Can you please help on this?

Comment: @Samya please refer to https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am a bit late here but I think this is still a quite common problem. What you have seen is that R is complaining about missing dependencies. You need to install A LOT OF packages before you are able to compile it. Here is a full list of them:

https://github.com/Jiefei-Wang/Painless-R-compilation-and-installation-on-Ubuntu

If you are using Ubuntu this is just a matter of copy and paste. Otherwise, you may need to take some time and figure out how to install them on your machine.